# Replace same string with different values per occurence

Tags: php

I'm trying replace the same string with different values per occurence, but I'm getting a big trouble and I have no idea about how to fix it.

```
$order = "john, book, 1";
$order = explode(',', $order);

$url = "https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/{}/data/{}/oc/v/{}/";
$repeat =  substr_count($url, "{}");

for ($i=0; $i<=$repeat; $i++) {
    $final .= str_replace('{}', $repeat[$i], $url);
}

echo $final;
```

Current output:

```
NOTICE Undefined variable: final on line number 10

https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author//data//oc/v/https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author//data//oc/v/https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author//data//oc/v/https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author//data//oc/v/
```

My expected output should be something like this:

```
https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/john/data/book/oc/v/1/
```

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Look at `sprintf`.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Did you forget to declare the `$final` variable?

Comment: `substr_count()` returns an integer, not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work

```
<?php

$order = "john, book, 1";
$order = explode(',', $order);


$url = "https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/{}/data/{}/oc/v/{}/";
$repeat =  substr_count($url, "{}");

$final = $url;

for ($i=0; $i < $repeat; $i++) {
    $final = preg_replace('/{}/', $order[$i], $final, 1);
}

echo $final;

?>
```

Comment: That would deliver `https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/john/data/john/oc/v/john/`, right? Because after the first iteration `$final` doesn't contain any more `{}`

Comment: it will deliver the expected output

Comment: That's funny, because for me it doesn't.

Comment: sorry, my mistake - `$final = preg_replace('/{}/', $order[$i], $final, 1);` .  i have to use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` - see editied answer

Comment: Not a problem. Maybe use `trim()`, because now you'll get `https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/john/data/ book/oc/v/ 1/` (including spaces)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your `$order` array will have only three values,

```
$order = "john, book, 1";
$order = explode(',', $order);

$url = "https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/%s/data/%s/oc/v/%s/";

echo sprintf($url, trim($order[0]), trim($order[1]), trim($order[2]));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/john/data/book/oc/v/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the URL an array with explode and join the two arrays in a loop.

```
$order = "john, book, 1";
$order = explode(', ', $order);


$url = "https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/{}/data/{}/oc/v/{}/";
$url = explode("{}", $url);
$final ="";

foreach($url as $key => $u){
    $final .= $u;
    if(isset($order[$key])) $final .= $order[$key];
}

echo $final;
//https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/author/john/data/book/oc/v/1/
```